# Getting the contents of a variable in a JS method asp.net C #

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a function that takes the values ​​of my inputs, and want to take the values ​​of my variable to hold the insert method. Anyone have any tips on how to do this?

```
function insert_veiculo() {
  var placa = $("#placa").val();
  var quilometragem = $("#quilometragem").val();
  var cor = $("#cor").val();
  var tipo = $("#tipo").val();
  var chassi = $("#chassi").val();
  var ano = $("#ano").val();
  var modelo = $("#modelo").val();
}
```

My method:

```
 protected void button1_cad_veiculo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Veiculo vl = new Veiculo();

        vl.Modelo1 = Request.Form["modelo"];
        vl.Quilometragem1 = Request.Form["quilometragem"];
        vl.Placa = Request.Form["placa"];
        vl.Cor = Request.Form["cor"];
        vl.Chassi = Request.Form["chassi"];
        vl.Tipo = Request.Form["tipo"];
        vl.

        VeiculoDAL.cadastra(vl);
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I need to pass the values ​​of my JavaScript variable to my C # method

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this , is set those value to a variable (hidden variable) and that should be in form field, so that on postback those values will be posted to page and you can do Request.Form["val"].

E.g. `<input type="hidden" id="hdplaca" />`

in js do following.

```
 $("#hdplaca").val( $("#placa").val() );
```

In C#

get this using `String s = Request.Form["hdplaca"].ToString();`

Comment: and how javaScript will pass or call my method to perform the insert?

Comment: Javascript will only set the values to hidden field only.
But when postback will happen, your code-behind will be able to access those and insert to DB.